# Buffer overflow using WebSockets in Play Framework

Tags: java, websocket, playframework, akka

On our online game using websockets, we get the following error several times a day:

```
ERROR p.c.s.common.WebSocketFlowHandler - WebSocket flow threw exception
akka.stream.BufferOverflowException: Buffer overflow (max capacity was: 16)!
```

We ran out of ideas on where to look at. Does anyone know why this happens?

Alternatively, is there any way we can enable debug info in Play Framework's WebSocketFlowHandler in order to understand why the buffer gets filled?

Comment: The default number of msgs in akka stream is 16. For sure the problem is in the akka stream config in Play, where if it is only akka I would use something like `
    val bufferedFlow = flow.buffer(40, overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.backpressure)`. But there is a long time that I used Play and I dont know where to point this configuration to you.

Comment: Maybe this is related to "Sending large amounts of data" at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaStream . what do you think? Maybe you can post the HttpRequest/Response that you use to consume the payload.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll check how to change the buffer size

Answer (score 0):

This config worked for me

```
akka.stream.materializer.max-input-buffer-size = 16384
```

Comment: What exactly does it do? What is the link with the stream materializer and the websocket?